# C# call List<User> to Main Class

Tags: c#, active-directory, console

I know this is very trivial, but unfortunately doesn't work for me at all. I have create a function which return List from `Active Directory`. And right now when I run application I didn't get any data in `Console`

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ActiverDirectory
{
    public class Korisnik
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Ime { get; set; }
        public string Prezime { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime AccountExpired { get; set; }
        public bool PassNevExp { get; set; }
        public string DomenskaGrupa { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"samaccountname: {Ime}, usergroup: {Prezime}";
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            foreach (Korisnik korisnik in VratiKorisnike())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(korisnik);
            }

        }



        public static List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()
        {
            List<Korisnik> lstADUsers = new List<Korisnik>();
            string sDomainName = "sarajevoosigura";
            string DomainPath = "LDAP://" + sDomainName;

            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath);
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("PasswordExpirationDate");


            DataTable resultsTable = new DataTable();
            resultsTable.Columns.Add("samaccountname");
            resultsTable.Columns.Add("displayname");
            resultsTable.Columns.Add("Neaktivan");
            resultsTable.Columns.Add("UserAccountContol");
            resultsTable.Columns.Add("PasswordExpirationDate");


            SearchResult result;
            //int i;
            SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

            if (resultCol != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter <= (resultCol.Count - 1); counter++)
                {
                    string UserNameEmailString = string.Empty;

                    result = search.FindOne();
                    if ((result.Properties.Contains("samaccountname") && result.Properties.Contains("displayname")))
                    {
                        Korisnik korisnik = new Korisnik();
                        korisnik.Ime = ((string)(result.Properties["samaccountname"][0]));
                        korisnik.Prezime = ((string)(result.Properties["displayname"][0]));
                        korisnik.AccountExpired = (DateTime)result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];
                        korisnik.PassNevExp = ((bool)result.Properties["PasswordExpirationDate"][0]);


                        DataRow dr = resultsTable.NewRow();
                        dr["samaccountname"] = korisnik.Ime;
                        dr["displayname"] = korisnik.Prezime.ToString();
                        dr["Nekativan"] = korisnik.AccountExpired.ToString();
                        dr["PassExp"] = korisnik.AccountExpired.ToString();
                        resultsTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                        lstADUsers.Add(korisnik);
                    }
                }
            }
            return lstADUsers;
        }


    }
}
```

I try

```
Console.WriteLine(VratiKorisnike<>);
```

Any help how to call this function to Main() `public List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()`

Comment: At first the method `VratiKorisnike` needs to be `static`, because `Main` is `static`, too. Then you don't want to `Console.WriteLine(VratiKorisnike)` because that would only print the type of the list, not the content. You need to iterate through the list and print the individual elements.

Comment: And you'll probably get the type name of `Korisnik` if you simply write the object without overriding `ToString()` in the `Korisnik` class.

Comment: I change public static List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike() and in `Main()`  add
Console.Write(VratiKorisnike()); nothing happened

Comment: foreach(var VratiKorisnika in VratiKorisnike())
            {
                Console.Write("Ukupan broj usera je", VratiKorisnike());
            }
Doesnt work in my case

Comment: to your last comment: you want to `Console.Write("Ukupan broj usera je", VratiKorisnika);` instead of calling `VratiKorisnike()`again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your approach. First of all any method you call without an instance of a class has to be static, but your `VratiKorisnike` method is not. You have to add [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) modifier ti it's declaration.

```
public static List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnike()
```

This will fix compile time error, but still won't give you result you are expecting, because

```
Console.WriteLine(VratiKorisnike());
```

is equivalent to

```
Console.WriteLine(VratiKorisnike().ToString());
```

which will simply print `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ActiverDirectory.Korisnik] ``

To get information about each instance of `Korisnik` class inside `List<Korisnik>` returned by `VratiKorisnike` method you have to override [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method inside `Korisnik` class and then call it on each element of your list.

Just add something like this to your `Korisnik` class

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Id: {Id}, Ime: {Ime} ... whatever other text you want";
}
```

Then you can use LINQ [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.8) extension method or simple `for`/`foreach` loop to get all those strings and print them. For example you could jus add this, to your `Main` method

```
foreach (Korisnik korisnik in VratiKorisnike())
{
    Console.WriteLine(korisnik);
}
```

Comment: Where to add this, sorry I didnt get it. Inside public static List<Korisnik> VratiKorisnika() method or ....

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Id: {Id}, Ime: {Ime} ... whatever other text you want";
}

Comment: I've made slight modification to my answer. Now before each code sample I explain where it should be placed inside your program

Comment: Thank you, but still nothing happened

Comment: If you're still having problems you probably should make sure your `VratiKorisnike` method works as expected. Using `Console.WriteLine` inside method or adding [breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) might help you with debugging it

Comment: I use `Console.WriteLine("Ime")` after every single line starting from start to end, and it prints out the result, but somehow User from ActiveDirectory can not be display

Comment: Thank you @Kacper, I found where the error comes from.